# Dopamine and other neurotransmitter release during music listening

Tags: brain, neurotransmitter, dopamine

I'm looking for any studies that show a positive curve in respects to music sessions in humans and neurotransmitter release (specifically dopamine, epinephrine, and serotonin.) Any direct links would be great as I attempted googling and cannot find any at all for some reason.

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5627/is-there-evidence-to-suggest-that-music-can-trigger-release-of-a-particular-kind/15203#15203

Comment: It's a lot easier to measure brain electrodes for alpha wave activity, and MRI brain scans while listening to music, so those are more common studies.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article I found on google scholar. It links an increase in 5-HT a serotonin neurotransmitter when listening to pleasant music.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s004060070031

Comment: Thats pretty funny. 3 years later i randomly look at this question ive posted and you answered within the past hour. Ill take a look. Cheers

Comment: Since links die more frequently than you think, please provide a citation in your post as well as a summary in your own words. We want answers to be useful for the long-term. Thanks!